# MySQL Group By with Sum removing too much information

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

Can anyone help me understand how MySQL's Group By works and what I'm doing wrong? I'm using a database with two tables, auctions and lots. The lot table has a column for 'auctionid' which links each lot to the relevant auction, with a one:many relationship between auctions and lots.

I'm selecting a large amount of information from both the lots and auctions, including using a couple of sum and count(distinct) functions to total some records in the lots table on a per-auction basis.

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT
  auction.`countryId`,
  auction.`date`,
  auction.`name`,
  auction.`awardComments`,
  lots.`lotName`,
  lots.`region`,
  lots.`popCovered`,

  SUM(lots.'size'),
  SUM(lots.`paired`),
  SUM(lots.`unpaired`),
  COUNT(DISTINCT 'lots.winner')

FROM auction join lots USING ('awardid') 

GROUP BY lots.'awardid'
```

'awardid' is the primary key for the auction table and the foreign key for the lots table. 'lotid' is the primary key for the lots table but isn't used.

When I run this query I get one row for each auction, what I'm looking for is one row for each lot, with the auction information the same for each lot in that auction and the sum and count functions counting the total sizes and number of winners for each auction from the lots table. If I get rid of the 'group by' and 'sum' parts of the query then I get the right number of lines, one for each lot. Is there a way of getting all the lines I need with the sum and count functions? Basically I only want the group clause to apply to the SUM and COUNT functions, if that makes sense - I want the number of winners calculated for each auction, but displayed in the results for each lot in that auction.

Comment: what is the candidate key for this table?

Comment: Looks like you missed a comma in the tables list: `from auction, lots`

Comment: @eugeney, he actually missed a `join` keyword.

Comment: @JStead, I don't know what a candidate key is - 'awardid' is the primary key for the auctions table and also links each lot record to its parent auction.

Comment: @Johan, yes I accidentally deleted the 'join' keyword when I edited down the query, added it back in, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  a.countryId,
  a.`date`,
  a.name,
  a.awardComments,
  l.lotName,
  l.region,
  l.popCovered,

  sums.total_size,
  sums.total_paired,
  sums.total_unpaired,
  sums.winners

FROM auction a
INNER JOIN lots l on (a.awardid = l.awardid) 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    a2.id as auction_id
    SUM(l2.size) as total_size,
    SUM(l2.paired) as total_paired,
    SUM(l2.unpaired) as total_unpaired,
    COUNT(DISTINCT l2.winner) as winners
  FROM AUCTION a2 INNER JOIN lots l2 ON (a2.awardid = l2.awardid)
  GROUP BY a2.id
  ) sums ON (sums.auction_id = a.id)
```

This does repeat the same totals per auction for lots that come from the same auction.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I know, the OP specifically asked for 1 line per lot. He already has the query per auction.

Comment: This gives me the right number of rows, but the SUM and COUNT functions aren't summing across lots, they're just giving me the answer for that lot - each lot has one winner, but I want to see how many different winners each auction has. I want each lot line to contain information about the auction overall as well as that particular lot.

Comment: All you should need to do is modify the GROUP BY clause of the query you say works to something like `GROUP BY a.id, l.id WITH ROLLUP` -- check it out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @Dereleased, that is incorrect. `GROUP BY a.id, l.id` is the same as `group by l.id` and the with rollup will give **one** grand total for all auctions; i.e. will give the wrong result if more than 1 auction is involved. `WITH ROLLUP` in general is not a bad idea though.

Comment: @Johan - I misunderstood the comment that the OP made; I was thinking multiple auctions, not multiple lots.  Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this could work (warning: untested!):

```
SELECT 
  auction.`countryId`,
  auction.`date`,
  auction.`name`,
  auction.`awardComments`,
  lots.`lotName`,
  lots.`region`,
  lots.`popCovered`,
  sums.`size`,
  sums.`paired`,
  sums.`unpaired`,
  sums.`winners`
FROM auction
JOIN lots USING (`awardid`)
JOIN (
  SELECT
    `awardid`,
    SUM(`size`) AS `size`,
    SUM(`paired`) AS `paired`,
    SUM(`unpaired`) AS `unpaired`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT lots.`winner`) AS `winners`
  FROM lots GROUP BY `awardid`
) AS sums USING (`awardid`)
```

That is, you do a subselect on the `lots` table to calculate the sums per auction, and then treat the results of that as if it were a separate table which you can join to the results.

Comment: Did you just copy-paste my answer :-? I don't think it will work though the `using` clause is ambiguous. And the subselect adds all lots, irrespective of which auction they belong to.

Comment: @Johan: Great minds think alike. :)  Anyway, the subselect should work: remember that `lots.awardid` is the foreign key to the auction table, so lots that have the same awardid belong to the same auction.  You could be right about the `USING` syntax, though; I _think_ it should work as is, but I haven't tested it.